# Request URL was not found, Django deployed

Tags: django, deployment

I have a project where a user can upload an image and then, the server display it. I have not problems in the production phase but when I upload my project to the server, this images are not displayed and when I click in the alt tag image I get redirected to a NOT FOUND page.

Note that the URL is right:

www.example.com/media/news_img/img.png

1. Project folder

   - server
   - templates
   - static
   - media

     - news_img

       - img.png

This just works when I enable **Debug mode**

HTML

`<a href="{{ news_f.news_img.url }}"><img src="{{ news_f.news_img.url }}" alt="{{news_f.news_tittle_es | safe}}"></a>`

I've seen this problem so many times but the solutions are from 2010-2013, I'm currently working on Djangno 2.7.

I've tried:

[Images from ImageField in Django don't load in template](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28837/discussion-between-paulo-bu-and-sheshkovsky)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using get_media_prefix and only pass the field name.

```
<img class="img-circle center-block m-t-1 m-b-2" src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ employee.photo }}" alt="Avatar">
```

Comment: This does not work for me, same error. It send me to the correct URL but it seems doesn't exists

Comment: Did you add media and static dir and url in your settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Comment: Yeah, I did. I've tried to set up the media_url manually but nothing change. It seams url can't access to the media folder